# getting API resolved without sending a response for this may result in stalled requests error in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

if I console.log the data in client side, it prints the data. But if I try to render the data, it doesn't render

And I getting the message API resolved without sending a response for /api/getdata, this may result in stalled requests.

api

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM todo`, (err, result) => {
      res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "Can't post" });
  }
};
```

clientside

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { url } from "../config";

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/api/getdata`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
};

export default function Home({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <Link href="/create">
        <a className="btn">Create New Todo</a>
      </Link>

      {data.map((elem) => {
        <h1>{elem.title}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```